# Force shading to a specific mode when opening a file

Tags: interface, blend-files

If you save and close a Blender file with the shading mode set to *Material Preview*, once you reopen the file the shading mode is still set this way. In the case of complex scenes with lots of materials and textures, this can potentially lead to a freeze of the entire interface for several minutes while Blender computes all the shaders.

There is a (paid) addon to avoid this, [Open Solid](https://blendermarket.com/products/open-solid).
Is there a way to do this manually, eg. using a command in the terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than changing it in Preferences, you can use <kbd>File</kbd>><kbd>Open</kbd> within Blender, then either press <kbd>N</kbd> or click the top-right Settings gear icon to bring up the Settings Panel. Then uncheck <kbd>Load UI</kbd> and load your file as usual. That will load the file into your default saved Blender view ignoring any UI settings in the loaded file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's currently not possible but there is a feature request open here [Always open file in Solid mode](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/gn9j/). Fortunately there is still a workaround. Under menu *Edit > Preferences > Save & Load*, temporarily untick the *Load UI* setting and then open your file. Then tick it back on.

[image]

Comment: If you reopen the file from a running instance of Blender you can do that from the 'N' panel of the file selector without having to go to preferences.

Comment: ah nice, thats good to know, can u post an answer coz im not really sure how exactly it works